# JQuery Add click event to existing code

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the code below and it works fine. My problem is the I need to click on the actually radio button to get the code to do it's thing.

I would like to also add a click handler so that is also triggers the event if the user click the div

Here is the current code:

```
<script>

$(function(){
$("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
$("input[type='radio']", $(this).parent().parent()).each(function() {
$(this).parent()
.toggleClass("class_selected", this.checked)
.toggleClass("class_default", !this.checked);

});
});
});

</script>
```

UPDATE: Here is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="def_app">
<span>Title Here</span>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" />
</div>
```

Comment: Assuming the Div is just the parent can you not do: $("input[type='radio']").parent().change(.....

Comment: Use  [`.trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML code as well..

Answer (score 0):

Use [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to emulate that an event has happened, and call the corresponding code associated with that event.

```
$(function(){
$("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
$("input[type='radio']", $(this).parent().parent()).each(function() {
$(this).parent()
.toggleClass("class_selected", this.checked)
.toggleClass("class_default", !this.checked);

});
});

//call trigger on the input
$("#yourdiv").click(function() {    
 $("input[type=radio]").trigger('change');
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you should just use a [`<label>`<sup>W3C specs</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9) instead of a `<div>` to wrap the radio button. This way the `change` event you are currently using will be triggered when the user click on the label text..

It is the semantic way, if I understood your question correctly..

---

**Update** *after seeing your html*

Just use

```
<label class="def_app">
<span>Title Here</span>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" />
</label>
```